# Flask Insert data into Database using MySQL

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-mysql

I am trying to insert data into MYSQL database
when I try my program I get an error "Not enough arguments for format 
the string" at the following line.

```
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB se
rver version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

**And my code**:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="", static_folder="static")

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="railway"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/store',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def store():
   if request.method=='POST':
      name=request.form['name']
      mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO railway (name) VALUES (%s)""",(name))
      mydb.commit()
      return "record inserted."
   else:
      return "s"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mycursor.execute(`INSERT INTO railway (name) VALUES (?)`,(name));
```

Comment: First take query in variable and log that query;

Comment: ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1

Comment: Simply try with a raw query `INSERT INTO railway (name) VALUES ('name')`

Comment: Its direcly insert the string 'name' into my database

Answer (score 0):

mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO railway (name) VALUES (%s)""", %(name,))
You forgot the %

Comment: [File "index.py", line 23
    mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO railway (name) VALUES (%s)""", %(name,))
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax] returns error

Comment: Please, recheck your code. `%(name,)` clearly looks wrong at least.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use comma after Values (,) in the using of C style format specifier syntax. This is the right syntax.

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO railway (name) VALUES (%s)"%(name,))
```